# Apache : redirect files with canonical path to the real directory?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to serve images with canonical path to the real directory, but without revealing it.

Like this with non existent directories :

```
     http://www.mysite.com/Canonical/Directory/Name/my-image.png
```

would be sent to the real directory on the server :

```
     http://www.mysite.com/img/my-image.png
```

The images are called with a relative path within the page `<img src="my-image.png" />` in order to inherit the canonical path.

I had this RewriteRule in mind, but won't work…

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$">
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.+) /img/$1 [L]
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But all that I'm getting is my wonderful 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) for `/img/$1` to work.

Comment: Nope, this didn't do the trick… Will continue to test different methods, but starting to go nuts :P